# Owin - Initialize IdP using metadata file/url

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I want to use Owin based SAML2 authentication without "hardcoding" any data. I have metadata file from IdP owner. Is there any way, how to just load this file (or point to url with metadata) and let provider initialize itself?

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...

    app.UseSaml2Authentication(CreateSaml2Options());
}


private static Saml2AuthenticationOptions CreateSaml2Options()
{
    var spOptions = CreateSpOptions();
    var saml2Options = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
    {
        SPOptions = spOptions
    };

    var idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("XXXXXXXXX"), spOptions)
    {
        AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
        Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpPost,
        SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri("XXXXXXXXX")
    };

    saml2Options.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);

    return saml2Options;
}
```

How to get XXXXXXXXX values from metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XXX is the EntityId, it is listed at the top of the metadata. Consider e.g. this metadata excerpt from stubidp.sustainsys.com:

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
ID="_a1f8bba0-9d9f-4107-bbed-b61cd3d9c67f" 
entityID="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Metadata" cacheDuration="PT15M"
validUntil="2018-12-19T18:51:08Z">
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
       <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
```

The XXX value you are looking for is the `entityID` attribute. In this case it is `https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Metadata`.

In the current version of the library, it is unfortunately not possible to get the EntityID from the metadata. I'm planning to fix that in a future version but it requires quite a lot of work. The reason is that the EntityID is the key in a dictionary and things would get very confusing it would be lazily initialized or changed later.

Comment: ok, so I don't need metadata and I have to "hardcode" all in configuration, right?

Comment: No, you just have to "hardcode" the entityID. The rest can be read from metadata.